# what app should I use to run a slide show on the HDMI out?

Tags: video, software-recommendation

We have a TV that is displaying what is basically a slide show: a series of static images that loop.  Right now a windows PC running powerpoint provides the video feed.

I was wondering if there is a low-overhead software package for the raspberry pi that could run a slideshow.  I would prefer not to use the X server, but I recognize there might be some really good solutions that require X. The invocation would be something like

```
slideshow --delay 8.0 -loop /media/1/slideshowpics/
```

although

```
while true; do 
    slideshow --delay 8.0 /media/1/slideshowpics/*
done
```

would also be fine.  I need some way for it to pick up new pictures that we upload via the network.

Bonus points if you can get it to overlay the current IP address with a keystroke.

Comment: Did you check `mplayer` ?

Comment: Not using the X server here is sort of like saying you want to drive somewhere without wheels because you feel they are too heavy and the car will be lighter without them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use my software [info-beamer](https://info-beamer.com/pi). Is a software to build all kinds of visualizations. I have example code ready that displays all [jpeg files in a directory](https://github.com/dividuum/info-beamer-nodes/blob/master/photos-fade/node.lua). Just put the node.lua together with all images into a single directory, then start info-beamer giving that directory as argument. It will automatically pick up new images that are put into the directory. You don't need to start X to run info-beamer.

Comment: I would say this is overkill, but http://www.schlockmercenary.com/2004-02-23 .

Answer (score 5):

[feh](http://feh.finalrewind.org/) is a simple image viewer that should do what you want. feh requires X11.

You can give it a list of files or directories or URLs.

It looks like you might be able to use the **--info** option to display the IP address.

For displaying images on the console (without X11) you can use [fbi](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/fbi.1.html). It is not a full featured as feh but it will do a simple slideshow.

Both fbi and feh can be installed via apt-get.

Comment: The feh I was able to install using `apt-get install feh` seemed to require X.  I was not able to find any flags to make it work without X11 in `man feh`.

Comment: You are correct.  feh does require X11.  I have used **fbi** for console image display.  I will update the answer.

Comment: Practically no GUI apps have flags to allow them to work outside of a GUI stack straight from a virtual console.  There are a handful of [framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer) apps, such as `fbi`, but these are very unusual since they usually then *can't* run under X (making them very specialized, i.e., of limited use value).   Put another way: I'm pretty sure `fbi` is your *only* choice here.

Answer (score 4):

For displaying just static images you can use fbi.

You probably want to have some control via your remote ssh session.  The method below gives you that.

`sudo apt-get -y install fbi` to install fbi

`sudo nano /home/pi/slideshow` to create an easy slideshow script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 = "stop" ]; then
   sudo kill `ps aux | awk '/fbi \-T/ { print $2}'`
else
  sudo fbi -T 3 -a -d /dev/fb0 -noverbose --readahead -t 3 -1 -l fileimagelist.lst 
fi
```

then `chmod +x /home/pi/slideshow`

(optionally) you can `sudo nano /boot/config.txt` to get rid of the black edges around the screen.  For example:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug
hdmi_drive=2
hdmi_group=0
hdmi_mode=0
overscan_left=-10
overscan_right=-10
overscan_top=-20
overscan_bottom=-27
```

It might take a while before you find the right exact overscan numbers for your system.

use `./slideshow` to start, `./slideshow stop` to stop.  In `fileimagelist.lst` you just list all pictures line by line.  This example uses the `-1` flag, so it quits after it finishes 1 cycle of the slideshow.  I need that because I have a seperate script which manages the `fileimagelist.lst` file.

I personally wouldn't show the IP on the screen itself.  Rather use a crontabbed script to ping a server with the hostname and IP.  Method to do this can be found over here, I've submitted this a couple days ago on this very same site.

Answer (score 1):

Check this project out. I think it is just what you need:
http://www.binaryemotions.com/digital-signage/raspberry-slideshow/

Answer (score 0):

I Think piSignage is suitable for your requirement . * am not sure if you can directly upload slides but you can create your slides with all the effects , the just save your ppt slide as video and upload your video to pisignage.com. It works right.you can test it out for free.

https://pisignage.com/